# Guardar a imagem associada a um Image control para disco

Tags: wpf, image

Vamos supor que é carregada uma imagem para o controlo *Image* do exemplo seguinte ...

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" />
<Image x:Name="image" />
```

Que código é necessário associar ao botão *button* de forma a surgir uma janela que faça a operação de "**Guardar Como ...**" da imagem para o disco?

Answer (score 0):

Esta foi a solução encontrada por mim:

```
private void guardarImagemDiscoDoPreviewButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Save As Dialog ...
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
    dlg.FileName = "imagem";
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".jpg";
    dlg.Filter = "Imagem JPEG|*.jpg";
    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    //Converter source da imagem num byte array
    byte[] ImageData = getJPGFromImageControl(previewImage.Source as BitmapImage);

    //Gravar a imagem no disco
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(ImageData)))
    {
        image.Save(dlg.FileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);  // Ou Png ...
    }
}

public byte[] getJPGFromImageControl(BitmapImage imageC)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(imageC));
    encoder.Save(memStream);
    return memStream.ToArray();
}
```

Neste caso o controlo Image tem o nome *previewImage*.